# Laravel Nova 404 when using hasMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

In my Laravel Nova project, I have a Page and a PageTranslation (model and resource). When adding a hasMany to my Resource fields, upon visiting the detail of the Page, I get a 404 error. This is my code

This is my Page Resource

```
<?php

namespace App\Pages\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Resource;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\HasMany;

class Page extends Resource
{
    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = 'App\Pages\Models\Page';

    /**
     * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $title = 'working_title';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public static $group = 'Pages';

    /**
     * The columns that should be searched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $search = [
        'id', 'working_title'
    ];

    /**
     * Eager load translations
     */
    public static $with = ['translations'];

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),

            Text::make('Title', 'working_title')
                ->sortable()
                ->rules('required', 'max:256'),

            HasMany::make('Translations', 'translations', \App\Pages\Resources\PageTranslation::class)

        ];
    }

}
```

This is my PageTranslation Resource

```
<?php

namespace Codedor\Pages\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Resource;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;

class PageTranslation extends Resource
{
    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = 'Codedor\Pages\Models\PageTranslation';

    /**
     * Hide resource from Nova's standard menu.
     * @var bool
     */
    public static $displayInNavigation = false;

    /**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),

            Text::make('Locale')
                ->sortable()
                ->rules('required', 'max:256')
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: Let me check! I'm not sure

Comment: It's still the same code, so I suppose it was something else causing the issue, I do see the namespace is included now, to a RESOURCE, not to a model, are you referencing the correct one?

Comment: I think so, I have other reources where the HasMany field works fine. But there is one that hangs on a 404 when calling to http://ostendenova.localhost/nova-api/productos/field/formulas Producto resource has many Formulas resource

Comment: Sorry can't help you with only that information, maybe you can create a stackoverflow thread with all the information? Someone might help you.

Comment: Yes, but first I'll try a little bit more, I think is a mistake in my code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a little bit late, but if anyone comes across this issue while using `Nova::resources` instead of the resources path inside `resources` method in `NovaServiceProvider`, make sure you add the related resource to the list.

If you wish to hide a resource from the sidebar navirgation, just use `public static $displayInNavigation = false;` inside the resource file

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to relationships at all. Make sure you've included the resources in your `NovaServiceProvider`
Also, to restrict from viewing in the sidebar based on user role, you can do something like:

```
 public static function availableForNavigation(Request $request)
 {
   return $request->user()->isAdmin();
 }
```